# 400 Bad request Error when http post from angular into .NET Core Web API

Tags: angular, post, .net-core

I am trying to post some values to my .NET core web api function from Angular. Its triggering an 400 bad request error. At the same time Get is working fine.

Here are my Web APIs

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<GenExternalActualDeletionLog> Get()
    {
        return _svc.DeletionLogs();
    }


    // POST api/<DeleteExternalActuals>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<List<GenExternalActualDeletionLog>> Post(String pCode,string[] expenseKeys)
    {
        return Ok(_svc.DeleteExternalActual(pCode, expenseKeys, _caller.Identity.Name).OrderByDescending(x => x.DeletedOn));
    }
```

And here is my angular service calling the web apis

```
 DeleteData(configuration: ExternalActualsDeleteData): Observable<any> {

this.baseUrl = this.conf.getSettings("apiUrl");

let hd = new HttpHeaders();
hd.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", 'application/json');
//alert(this.baseUrl +'/api/closure/ClosureOverride');
console.info(configuration);
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/api/DeleteExternalActuals', {pCode:configuration.pCode,expenseKeys:configuration.expenseKeys});

}

GetAllDeleteLogs(): Observable<ExternalActualsDeleteLog[]> {

this.baseUrl = this.conf.getSettings("apiUrl");
return this.http.get<ExternalActualsDeleteLog[]>(this.baseUrl + "/api/DeleteExternalActuals").pipe(
  catchError((err) => {
    console.log('error caught in  service')
    console.error(err);

    //Handle the error here

    return throwError(err);    //Rethrow it back to component
  })
);
```

}

Here only post shows error. Get working fine. Is it because of the way I am sending parameter? or anything else? The call is not even reaching the server side api. Thats why I thought about the parameter

Comment: Are you sending antiforgery token with the post request? From what I see, it is not sent in the angular request. Usually web Api requires it. Try putting the [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]  attribute above the HttpPost action in your controller and see if it makes a valid request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap your data with Dto and set the [FromBodyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.frombodyattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Try this:

```csharp
public record PostDeleteExternalActualsDto(string pCode, string[] expenseKeys);
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<List<GenExternalActualDeletionLog>> Post([FromBody] PostDeleteExternalActualsDto data)
```